# Sorting by first digit not whole number

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-lists

I have a script, the goal of which is to sort a list of entire div classes (containing images) in ascending order as determined by a number within that div class. It has to work at the push of a button. It works relatively well, except it keeps sorting the items by the first digit rather than the number as a whole (resulting in an arrangement like 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, etc.)

My entire code is below, please show me how to fix this.

NOTE: I am looking for any possible solution but if it's possible to keep the script close to its current form I would prefer that

CSS:

```
.number{
 display:block;
 color:black;
 font-size:30px;
 margin:20px
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sortingbutton">
<button>Sorting Button</button>
</div>

</div>
<ul id="list">

<li>
<div class="number">5</div>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b70bLk1.png" width="250px" height="250px" alt="aqua" /> 
</li>
<li>
<div class="number">4</div>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/keE5Thi.png" width="250px" height="250px" alt="tan" /> 
</li>
<li>
<div class="number">1</div>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EgqCTZJ.png" width="250px" height="250px" alt="black" /> 
</li>
<li>
<div class="number">3</div>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/4onkGsz.png" width="250px" height="250px" alt="grey" /> 
</li>
<li>
<div class="number">9</div>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/To88ZFN.png" width="250px" height="250px" alt="orange" /> 
</li>
<li>
<div class="number">2</div>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6ZtB1VW.png" width="250px" height="250px" alt="purple" /> 
</li>
<li>
<div class="number">6</div>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5Pz2Q2Y.png" width="250px" height="250px" alt="yellow" /> 
</li>
<li>
<div class="number">7</div>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VqAdV1K.png" width="250px" height="250px" alt="blue" /> 
</li>
<li>
<div class="number">8</div>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/4HCxTpm.png" width="250px" height="250px" alt="green" /> 
</li>
<li>
<div class="number">10</div>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JjjHmM0.png" width="250px" height="250px" alt="pink" /> 
</li>
<li>
<div class="number">11</div>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EpB8YgU.png" width="250px" height="250px" alt="Red" /> 
</li>

</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
var desc = false;
document.getElementById("sortingbutton").onclick = function () {
    sortUnorderedList("list", desc);
    desc = !desc;
    return false;
}
}

function compareText(a1, a2) {
 var t1 = a1.innerText,
     t2 = a2.innerText;
return t1 > t2 ? 1 : (t1 < t2 ? -1 : 0);
}

function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
    if (typeof ul == "string") {
        ul = document.getElementById(ul);
   }

var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var vals = [];

for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
    vals.push(lis[i]);
}

vals.sort(compareText);

if (sortDescending) {
    vals.reverse();
}

ul.innerHTML = '';
for (var i = 0, l = vals.length; i < l; i++) {
    ul.appendChild(vals[i]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `a1.innerText - a2.innerText` in `compareText`?

**Explanation**

When you compare two strings using less and greater than symbols javascript doesn't convert them to integers, as javascript can compare two strings, no problem. For example `"10" > "2"` returns `true`, cause `"10"` is longer.

However when you use subtraction operator javascript can't subtract strings so it converts it into integers.

Comment: I believe converting to integers would be cleaner solution.

Comment: I think it is a matter of preference, but but don't forget to provide second argument to `parseInt` as it can produce nasty bugs.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean, I thought I was already using a1.innerText - a2.innerText in compareText? If I'm mistaken please show me how.

Comment: Its much more a matter of clean code and optimality. In your solution you convert string into integers each time you call compareText function (optimality).  You may need another numerical operations over the list in the future (because they are real numbers, not just strings), you would have to hack it again (clean code)...

Comment: You are using t1 > t2, not a1.innerText - a2.innerText.

Comment: @Jack Elwell I have added some short explanation.

Comment: I understand what you mean with your explanation, and I believe that this is the solution I am looking for, but when I enter the changes I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected token. Perhaps I'm just entering them wrong? t1 - t2 isn't working either.

Comment: I have copied all your code (except window.onload) and just replaced line 12 and for me everything works just fine - https://jsfiddle.net/oee8aw8n/

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt to convert string variables into integers.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Sorting by first digit is string sorting.

```
for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
    vals.push(parseInt(lis[i], 10));
}
```